# Convert equations into Outlined EPS or SVG format by using TeX4ht

Tags: tex4ht, svg, htlatex

I've tried with:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

This is for test $a+b=c$
\begin{align*}
\int+\prod=\sum
\end{align*}

This is for test $d+e=f$
\begin{align*}
\alpha+\beta=\gamma
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

My expectation is, I need to convert both the `inline math` and `display math` into either `outlined EPS` format or `SVG` format separately, is it possible by executing `htlatex`? Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, picture math is the worst option for the accesibility, it also doesn't look really well. It is better to use MathML with MathJax rendering, or just MathJax. Both of these options are supported by TeX4ht. If you really want to use pictures, you can use various [options that starts with pic-](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/texfourhtOptions.html#-texht-options1). For example, for inline math, you can use `pic-m`, and for the `align*` environment, `pic-align`. There is also the  `svg` option for SVG pictures.

If you have many equations and inline math, the compilation can take a lot of time, as each picture needs to be converted separately. You can use the `dvisvgm_hashes` make4ht extension for speed-up. It converts only math environments that were changed since the last compilation, and it also runs parallel conversion, so it is much faster.

This is the command that you can use:

```
$ make4ht -f html5+dvisvgm_hashes -m draft -a debug sample.tex "svg,pic-m,pic-align"
```

See also the [picture math How-to](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/Howto.html#picture-math).

This is the result:

[image]

If you want to produce EPS images (note that they are not supported by web browsers, so I am not sure that it is a good idea), you need to do two things: change the extension of generated graphics, and declare command that can convert DVI to EPS.

You can change the extension using this config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{Picture}{.eps}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

And EPS can be created using  `dvips`. Try this build file, `build.lua`:

```lua
Make:image("eps$", "dvips  -E -o ${output} -pp ${page} ${source}")
```

You can then compile your file using:

```
$ make4ht -c config.cfg -e build.lua filename.tex "pic-m,pic-align"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, based on your reply, may I assume that there is no possibility to convert into outlined EPS format? please suggest...

Comment: @MadyYuvi you can convert to `eps`, you just need to use a build file and declare command for DVI to EPS conversion, see https://www.kodymirus.cz/make4ht/make4ht-doc.html#image-conversion Note that EPS format is not supported by web browsers, so I am not sure if it is really useful.

Comment: @MadyYuvi I've updated my answer with instructions for EPS

Comment: Fantastic, exactly matched with the requirement, thanks a lot